# Does redis SLOWLOG command measure CPU time or real time?

Tags: redis

Redis [SLOWLOG](https://redis.io/commands/slowlog) logs the time of slow commands in redis. The time logged is in microseconds. However, I am not sure if the time is CPU time or real time. So, if the machine is under heavy load, and the redis process is being starved, will that cause more slow log entries on otherwise fast commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SLOWLOG gives time in wall clock sense, not CPU. Entries are added to the log when commands exceed the configured threshold for execution time. If the CPU is starve and regular or fast operations take longer to complete and exceed the threshold they will indeed be added to the log.

Comment: Thanks. So, to be clear, if we have a CPU-starved machine, we can expect more slowlog entries than on a machine with a free-er CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Redis uses real time instead of CPU one.

After searching over the Internet I've found interesting link about redis slowlog](http://blog.wjin.org/posts/redis-slowlog.html), that gave me an idea to search through source code of Redis.

According to the source code it turns out that data in slowlog is added by the call of [this function](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/2bf8c2c1300da1909cc8c8c35d13e46bcf59aa31/src/slowlog.h#L46)
`void slowlogPushEntryIfNeeded(client *c, robj **argv, int argc, long long duration);` .

After searching where this funciton is called only inside [server.c](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/bb3b5ddd1968d2715acc37b63124ccf461276160/src/server.c#L2232) file.

So the duration is logged there, and it is produced from [this code snippet].(https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/bb3b5ddd1968d2715acc37b63124ccf461276160/src/server.c#L2207)

```
start = ustime();
c->cmd->proc(c);
duration = ustime()-start;
```

And ustime is produced with the [following source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/bb3b5ddd1968d2715acc37b63124ccf461276160/src/server.c#L400):

```
/* Return the UNIX time in microseconds */
long long ustime(void) {
    struct timeval tv;
    long long ust;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    ust = ((long long)tv.tv_sec)*1000000;
    ust += tv.tv_usec;
    return ust;
}
```

So [gettimeofday](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) is responsible for duration production and it shows the **real** time instead of CPU.

Comment: Nice answer, but I already awarded the correct answer to the other answer.